# Removed file is still accessible by collaborators in Google Drive. How I can delete it completely?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

When I am deleting a file from Google drive which someone else shared with me, it showed me a message like "one removed file is still accessible by collaborators".

It no longer appears in that folder, but will it be shown in "shared with me"? How can I delete it completely?

Comment: Questions are: Why does this message show? To whom does it show (already answered below)? Does it still count against my Google Drive Quota? How can I delete it so that it does NOT count against my Google Drive Quota?

Comment: My experience on this question is renewing my confidence in stack overflow.  My request to reopen a question was not only considered, it seems it led to someone answering it, and someone else providing natural English grammar. Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr
To completely delete a file in gdrive of **owner** of the removed file:

1. Search for `is:unorganized owner:me`
2. Delete the file
3. Remove it from trash (delete it permanently)

Explanation:
This is a common problem with Google Drive. Files removed from the **Shared folder** loses the location pointer and stays on the drive of the **owner of the file** with lost **location property** (cannot be accessible in standard way as we browse files in Google Drive).
The removed file can be found by searching for it by name or content, or using suggested the search phrase `is:unorganized owner:me`.

A scenario that commonly causes this problem and fix:

- **U** (as you) and **S**(someone else) have shared a folder with name `Cats pictures`
- **U** adds `cat.jpg` (and **U** is an **owner of this file** then)
- **S** doesn’t like this picture and uses option `Remove`
- The message `removed file are still accessible by collaborators` pops up
- File `cat.jpg` **is removed from shared folder** `Cats pictures`
- **S** is happy and never sees a `cat.jpg` in `Cats pictures` folder
- **U** cannot see this file either in `Cats pictures` folder but `cat.jpg` is still on **U** private Google Drive!
- If **U** searches in Google Drive for `cat.jpg` it finds the file, and its location will be `-` (file lost it's location in folder tree).
- The file found by **U** can be moved to **Trash** and then completely deleted.

Comment: I can say that this technique DID find some files that had disappeared earlier.  Whether they will free noticeable disk space after I delete them -- that remains to be seen.

Comment: Sadly, this does not show ALL files -- or there may be an eventual consistency issue.  I just deleted a rather large file, and got the "removed file are still accessible by collaborators" message. But "is:unorganized owner:me"  does not show the file... at least, not immediately!

Comment: In this case, I found the file with "owner:me is:trashed" and permanently deleted it.

Comment: Hoorah! Indeed, deleting the file found with "owner:me is:trashed" did result in freeing up drive space!

Comment: @JosiahYoder-deactiveexcept.. exactly - first you need to find those files and then if removed to trash you need to delete it to free up the space

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you'd deleted the file from Google drive which was shared by someone else with you. After deleting you saw a message that stated, "one removed file is still accessible by collaborators". Perhaps the one who is sharing the file is one of the mentioned collaborators, or depending on how this document was shared, other members of the group.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Rename file a number then delete twice or 3 times it won't recognize it I had 6and there gone now